# Undefined index error in Large file uploads

Tags: php

i am trying to write upload script. Using uniform server on windows 7. My upload_max_size is 10M. I want to control that if user try  send correct size of file or not. So im cheking error code with this code. [Here](http://pastebin.ca/2476332)

```
print_r($_FILES['userfile']['error'];
```

This code works when i try small file from limit and shows 0 on screen. But if i try large file from limit, then does not show error code, gives undefined index error. How can i solve this, and see error code when i try loading exceeded file size?

Thanks.

Comment: At what filesize does the error appear?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking why it produces Undefined Index error or how to prevent this?

Comment: I dont understand, sorry?

Comment: Please show more code and which line the undefined index error appears exactly.

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && ($_FILES['userfile']['error'])) { ... }`

Comment: @Pekka웃 Notice: Undefined index: userfile in C:\UniServer\www\calisma\upload.php on line 10

Comment: We need to see the code as well.

Comment: @Pekka웃 i added code to question

Comment: Try `print_r()` ing the entire `$_FILES` array and seeing what goes wrong. Most likely, the file wasn't uploaded at all.

Comment: @Pekka웃 yes right, but i mean that in small file print_r($_FILES) works but in big files does not. so how will i check if user exceed max upload size? is_uploaded_file ? or something?

Comment: You'll definitely need to check whether the file exists. But it sounds weird that a file that is too large would not cause any error at all. Could be a case where there is a *server* setting (like Apache's post_max_size) that takes away the uploaded file before PHP can do anything

Answer (score 0):

There are several limiting factors for the file size (depending on the server):

- The upload_max_size you mentioned.
- A upper limit for HTTP Post data (or whichever HTTP Method you use)
- A (soft) upper limit in the client's browser
- Timeouts limiting the file size due to the limited response time
- Proxies

Check the other ones and *never* rely on any files. Always check existance.

Answer (score 0):

Open all your php.ini like files, search for post_max and upload_max and change their values to 1000M